# Making a View scroll once bottom is reached

Tags: android, scroll, android-view

Im trying to create a layout with following looks and behaviour.

```
<Layout>
  <Text "Header"/>
  <List> "Contains a couple of texts, most likely LinearLayout" </List>
  <Button "Confirm"/>
</Layout>
<Text "Information/Hint"/>
```

- Top-Level Layout is centered on the screen
- Information-Text is placed right beneath it (Layout is centered without accounting for this text)
- **Once the list fills to the point where the Information-Text is pushed out of the screen, the List starts scrolling and the Information-Text remains visible at the bottom of the screen. Distance of the top-border of the top-level-layout to the screen-border is the same as the hight of the information-text**
- **The scrolling-behaviour also takes action if the android-system-settings increased display/text-size to the point where said borders are reached**

Its the last two points that give me trouble. I've been experimenting with ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout, but every time the scrolling would work the layout wasn't correct anymore (not centered or margins on the texts screwed)

Any ideas how this could be achived without writing a custom Layout?

Answer (score 0):

Do your view hierarchy like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <Layout>
      <Text "Header"/>
      <List> "Contains a couple of texts, most likely LinearLayout" </List>
      <Button "Confirm"/>
    </Layout>
    <Text "Information/Hint"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This would scroll the entire view, i want the top-level layout to expand until it would push the information-hint out of the screen and then the list to start scrolling. only the list, not the header, button or information-text